# How to retain the existing database even after updating the app from android market?

Tags: android

I have an app which is released to google playstore. Now i need to release the new updated version of the app. But the condition is the existing contents of the database should not be modified or deleted.In addition to the old database ,my new databasse contents also should be copied when the updated version is installed into users device.I have put my database in asset folder. I tried using on upgrade method like below.when i execute application will be crashed.

```
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    Log.d("Test", "in onUpgrade. Old is: " + oldVersion + " New is: " + newVersion);*/

    if(newVersion > oldVersion){                    
        rssContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: Updating the app **will not** delete the application's data (database, shared preferences etc.). So, you have nothing to worry as long as it is in the app's storage. Consider copying the database from assets to the internal/external storage and accessing it from there. On upgrade you can simply add the contents of the new database to the older one.

Comment: can you please suggest me the implementation..thanks

Comment: Yeah sure. Copy the database from the **assets** folder to the internal storage and then access it. Try this : http://androidtutorials60.blogspot.in/2013/03/1.html

Comment: i have doubt that if i upgrade the app do i lose the application data and database contents??

Comment: stil i have doubt. while releasing updates we will add the new apk file to playstore. does it effects my previous database ? what actually happens? is it like uninstalling the app?..

Comment: Assuming the databases have the same name, then **yes**, the older one will be overwritten. This can be handled by checking if the File exists(). Then rename the existing file, merge it's contents with the newer database and delete the older database.